# Dynamic .PivotFields parameters

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a macro to automatically expand a specific field in a PivotTable. I have got the macro to work how I want it.

Is there a way to make a specific part of it a variable so that as the month changes that needs to be expanded, I can quickly update it, or make a userform to update it as well?

Here is the code as it stands:

```
    For Each pt In ws1.PivotTables
pt.PivotFields( _
    "[Date].[ByCalendar].[Calendar Month]").PivotItems( _
    "[Date].[ByCalendar].[Calendar Month].&[2015]&[4]").DrilledDown = True
Next pt
```

The part I want to set as a variable is `.&[2015]&[4]` I need to be able to change it quickly to say `.&[2015]&[5]` etc without needed to always go into the code and manually change that part. I have about 20 tables that get updated.

Comment: Do you want it to update each month, so [2015]&[4] will change to [2015]&[5] at the start of may?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it updating for every new month. You want to change

```
"[Date].[ByCalendar].[Calendar Month].&[2015]&[4]"
```

to

```
"[Date].[ByCalendar].[Calendar Month].&[" & year(now) & "]&[" & month(now) & "]"
```

it gets "now" from the system clock. So if you want to test it change the date on the system clock and then update it.